# Update event handling in Access form

Tags: forms, vba, events, ms-access

I’m newbie in VB and Access. So I have table with Yes/No column „Channged”, and some text column, when I change text in text field (using form) I want to set Changet to true.

In my form, I handle Update event:

```
Private Sub Question_Updated(Code As Integer)

End Sub
```

How can I update Changed column through this method? Thanks.

Comment: If the yes/no is bound, then just "Me.YesNo = True"

Comment: No I don't have yes/no element on form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to set your Yes/No UNBOUND field as long as it is included in your recordset for the form.  Note that I am using the 'AfterUpdate event for the field you will be changing. The update will take place AFTER you move to another record or close the form.

```
Private Sub Question_AfterUpdate()
    Me!YesNo = vbYes
End Sub
```